# Most efficient way to calculate mean of a large array?

Tags: python, statistics, mean

I have some large .csv files of experimental data. Their sizes are in the range 30MB-3GB. I have successfully read them in using pandas and have performed some other calculations on the data. As it stands I have an extremely long 1D array which I need to take the mean of.

By default I used statistics.mean(array) but this seems to be taking an incredibly long time to run.

Through testing individual sections of my code, I know for definate that it is the line statistics.mean(array) that is taking so long to run.

Is there a more efficient way to calculate the mean of large data sets than this?

Thanks!

```
def GetMean(ionVelocityArray):
    return stats.mean(ionVelocityArray)
```

I have been waiting for 2 hours for this function to finish running on a 30MB file.

Comment: That seems really surprising; 30 MB isn't all that large these days, it seems like there must be something else going on. How does the processing time scale with the size of the array? Can you do something like `stats.mean(myarray[0:n])` for different values of n, such as 10^m for m = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and estimate how long it would take for the whole array?

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the size of the array you could just loop over it and divide by the size of the array at the end:

```
def GetMean(ionVelocityArray):
    total = 0
    for _ in ionVelocityArray:
       total += 1

    return total / len(ionVelocityArray)
```

But if it over 20k elements i would sort the array and do and estimate by using the inter-quartile range and use that to work out the mean or if there are repeat values then when it is sorted you could store in a dictionary where the key is an element from the list and the value is t6he count and use that for a mean.

Answer (score 0):

I carried out a simple test using `statistics.mean` and `numpy.mean` with a random 1D array having `1e8` floats which has a size in memory of 800 MB. I am using a common laptop.

The time necessary to compute the mean using the `statistics` library was 95 s, while it took just 0.11 s using `numpy`. Here is the code:

```py
import statistics
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np

test_array = np.random.rand(100_000_000)
size_in_memory = test_array.size * test_array.itemsize * 1e-6

t0 = perf_counter()
mean_statistics = statistics.mean(test_array)
tf_statistics = perf_counter() - t0

t0 = perf_counter()
mean_numpy = np.mean(test_array)
tf_numpy = perf_counter() - t0
```

If you can, use `numpy`.